# react-native-navigation v2 push screen from redux-saga to a specific tab

Tags: react-native-navigation

I have tab based app.

How to open(push) and focus new screen from the second tab.

Idealy I want to do it using redux-saga.

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [{
        stack: {
          children: [{
            component: {
              name: 'example.FirstTabScreen',
              passProps: {
                text: 'This is tab 1'
        ...
        stack: {
          children: [{
            component: {
              name: 'example.SecondTabScreen',
              passProps: {
                text: 'This is tab 2'
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in switching RNN tabs programmatically via Redux, here is the library designed to work with RNN via Redux [react-native-navigation-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation-redux)

All you need to switch tab using this library is simply dispatch switchTabToIndex action

```
dispatch(switchTabToIndex('BottomTabsId', 2));
```